# How to add custom column in tabular form?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

My current tabular form just displaying some columns from table.

How/where can I add custom column in tabular form, which will be link or button and will take to another page with some input information from that row?

Example

```
ID [Name] [Address] [Link or button here]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add custom column:

Go to "Region Definition" -> "Source", add new column to SQL query there. For example:

```
select col1, -- column of table
       col2, -- column of table
       'some text' custom_column -- custom column that will contain text "some text" 
                                 -- in every row
from my_table
```

Go to "Report Attributes", select column with name "Custom column" and click the "Edit" button (pencil picture), then go to "Column link" and fill fields:

- Link text - text to display, you can write your own static text, text from any column of query or picture
- Target - page in application or link to any outer site
- Page - number of your target page
- Item - item on target page that will receive value from your link
- Value - value, that you will send to that item. It can be either static value or value of any column of query (in this case use substitution string: "#" symbol and column name: #column_name#).

See documentation for understanding APEX URL syntax: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37097_01/doc/doc.42/e35125/concept_url.htm