# How to fetch and show data from multiple tables into Report?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I would like fetch data from multiple tables into single report, each table rendering in separated region. Then edit button on record will take to corresponding details page for that table. Tables have column, which can link them.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Two questions: 1) what type of region you want in report page? 2) you want editing on the same page or on another?

Comment: Dmitry, 1) Interactive Report region 2) Editing on another page

Comment: I figured out that it's impossible to create more than one interactive regions in single page. So question number one would be "any type, which will provide link to another page, where I can edit data"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most simple way to place 4 reports on one page is to take simple reports (`Create New page` or `create new region` -> `Report` -> `Classic report`).
To add link: [How to add custom column in tabular form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26550615/how-to-add-custom-column-in-tabular-form/26563831#26563831)
For editing page:

- edit one row of table - `Create New page` or `create new region` ->
  `Form` -> `Form on table or view`;
- edit many rows of table `Create new page` or `create new region` -> `Form` -> `Master-Detail Form` or `Tabular Form`.

Also, as I know, there is a way to put more then one tabular form on a page, but it is quite hard and I don't know details.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is a bit old topic, maybe it will help to someone...
Current APEX version is 18.2.
First, create new page as an interactive report.
You will have this new report placed inside content body as region entity.
Then just manually add another interactive report (chose from region collection of available objects; not items, not buttons but regions) into content body.
I have one such page with three interactive reports.