# How to open another page in new window and set form's text field's value taken from previous page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, oracle-apex

I have a page "Report", where each record has a link. When i click on it, I want to open another page with form in new tab/window, and automatically set a value based on clicked link.

For example if first record's some ID_PK=1 and I click on that record's link, I want to have this value set in form's field (ID_FK) when i open it.

I have tried some simple dynamic actions, some PL/SQL queries, but nothing helped much. How do I make it work?

Comment: Couldn't you pass a GET attribute in the URL when you open a new window ?

Comment: Just made it work, didn't notice before that I can set those values in "Column link" where I choose the page to be open. Not sure if that's what you meant, but thanks anyway

Comment: Here I explained how to create links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26550615/how-to-add-custom-column-in-tabular-form/26563831#26563831. Also, use tag `oracle-apex`, not `apex`.

Comment: look at http://rowantraining.blogspot.in/2013/08/oracle-apex-42-creating-modal-window.html , which is modal window